# What is the correct way to close a stream in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream

While playing around with streams and buffers, I ran into a problem:

I wrote the following silly program:

```
const net = require('net');
const stream = require('stream');

class MyReadable extends stream.Readable {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);

  }

  _read(size) {
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    this.push(value > 8 ? null : value.toString())
  }
}

const server = net.createServer((client) => {
  const readStream = new MyReadable()

  readStream.pipe(client)
  client.pipe(process.stdout)
  readStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('done')
    client.destroy()
    readStream.destroy()
  })
})

server.listen(7000)
```

And after connecting several times with telnet, I'm getting these warnings:

```
(node:1919) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1919) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1919) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1919) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1919) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 finish listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I'm thinking maybe I'm not closing objects I'm creating, or I'm creating the `readStream` at the wrong place. But those are just guesses, and I have added `readStream.destroy()` and that didn't seem to help.

I'm missing something big here, I'm sure, but I don't know what. Where and how should I close the stream? Am I creating it badly in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use pipe method incorrectly, it should be smth like this

```
client.pipe(readStream)
readStream.pipe(process.stdout)
client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('done')
  readStream.destroy()
})
```

Also your custom stream must be duplex(because we read from the stream and write into there) , therefore you also have to implement `_write()` method.